# JSON schema, check for object existence depending on member value

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a few JSON files that look like as follow:

**data_A.json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "params_id": "data_A",
        "params": {
            "A_params": {
                "XXX": null,
                "BLABLA": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**data_B.json**

```
{
    "data": {
        "params_id": "data_B",
        "params": {
            "B_params": {
                "XXX": null,
                "BLABLA": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to validate the existance of `"A_params"` only, only if `"params_id": "data_A"`. The same for `"B_params"`. Is it possible to achieve this behavior ?

I think I could apply nested `"if-then-else"` conditions, but maybe exists a better way..

If so, what is the appropriate JSON schema rule for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, a nested `if-then-else` (in combination with a `const` to check for the value) is the usual way to do this with the current JSON Schema specification. This is possible if the number of variations is limited.

The [other options](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html) to apply schemas conditionally are focused on the presence of properties.